# iam unable to browse internet through tata photon while local area connection is established on 12.04

Tags: 12.04

TATA photon is installed properly and it's working fine after disconnecting the local area connection

Comment: @Ron: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem. You can not use internet through wifi and LAN at the same time. Only one will be used at any time.

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers...  ;-)